# Why I can't use urlencode to encode json format data?

Tags: python, json, urlencode, python-2.7

I have a problem about urlencode in python 2.7:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import json
>>> urllib.urlencode(json.dumps({'title':"hello world！",'anonymous':False,'needautocategory':True}))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1280, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because `urllib.urlencode` ["converts a mapping object or a sequence of two-element tuples to a “percent-encoded” string..."](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). Your string is neither of these.

I think you need `urllib.quote` or `urllib.quote_plus`.

Comment: This does not work for Python 3. For python3, `urllib` is splitted into several modules. We need to use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode).

Answer (score 23):

[`urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) can encode a dict, but not a string. The output of `json.dumps` is a string.

Depending on what output you want, either don't encode the dict in JSON:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'title':"hello world！",'anonymous':False,'needautocategory':True})
'needautocategory=True&anonymous=False&title=hello+world%EF%BC%81'
```

or wrap the whole thing in a dict:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'data': json.dumps({'title':"hello world！",'anonymous':False,'needautocategory':True})})
'data=%7B%22needautocategory%22%3A+true%2C+%22anonymous%22%3A+false%2C+%22title%22%3A+%22hello+world%5Cuff01%22%7D'
```

or use [`quote_plus()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote_plus) instead (`urlencode` uses `quote_plus` for the keys and values):

```
>>> urllib.quote_plus(json.dumps({'title':"hello world！",'anonymous':False,'needautocategory':True}))
'%7B%22needautocategory%22%3A+true%2C+%22anonymous%22%3A+false%2C+%22title%22%3A+%22hello+world%5Cuff01%22%7D'
```

Comment: Note that `quote_plus()` will transform your spaces in `+`. When dealing with JSON you might want to keep them as `%20`, use `quote()` for that

Answer (score 3):

**(1) Import libraries**

```python
import requests
import json
```

**(2) Spec is a dictionary object**

```python
spec = {...}
```

**(3) Convert dictionary object to `json`**

```python
data = json.dumps(spec, ensure_ascii=False)
```

**(4) Finally, do request with parameter spec in `json` format**

```python
response = requests.get(
    'http://localhost:8080/...',
    params={'spec': data}
)
```

**(5) Analyze response ...**

Answer (score 3):

For those of ya'll getting the error:

> AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlencode'

It's because `urllib` has been split up in Python 3

---

### Here's the code for Python 3:

```python
import urllib.parse

data = {
    "title": "Hello world",
    "anonymous": False,
    "needautocategory": True
}

urllib.parse.urlencode(data)
# 'title=Hello+world&anonymous=False&needautocategory=True'
```

Comment: Works for me on Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

[`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) returns a string.

[`urllib.urlencode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) expects a query in the format of a mapping object or tuples. Note that it does not expect a string.

You're passing the first as the parameter for the second, resulting in the error.